# Scala Graph Cycle Detection Algo 'return' needed?

Tags: scala, detection, cycle

I have implemented a small cycle detection algorithm for a DAG in Scala.
The 'return' bothers me - I'd like to have a version without the return...possible?

```
  def isCyclic() : Boolean = {
    lock.readLock().lock()
    try {
      nodes.foreach(node => node.marker = 1)
      nodes.foreach(node => {if (1 == node.marker && visit(node)) return true})
    } finally {
      lock.readLock().unlock()
    }
    false
  }

  private def visit(node: MyNode): Boolean = {
    node.marker = 3

    val nodeId = node.id
    val children = vertexMap.getChildren(nodeId).toList.map(nodeId => id2nodeMap(nodeId))
    children.foreach(child => {
      if (3 == child.marker || (1 == child.marker && visit(child))) return true
    })

    node.marker = 2

    false
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem can be solved without changing the state of the node with the marker field. The following is a rough code of what i think the isCyclic should look like. I am currently storing the node objects which are visited instead you can store the node ids if the node doesnt have equality based on node id.

```
def isCyclic() : Boolean = nodes.exists(hasCycle(_, HashSet()))

def hasCycle(node:Node, visited:Seq[Node]) = visited.contains(node) || children(node).exists(hasCycle(_,  node +: visited))


def children(node:Node) = vertexMap.getChildren(node.id).toList.map(nodeId => id2nodeMap(nodeId))
```

Comment: I think you may want something with faster .contains than a Seq? Or hasCycle is O(number-of-nodes^2) when it could be O(number-of-nodes)

Comment: Also, this pattern of creating a new (in this case) visited for each recursive call always feels to me like being functional just for the sake of it and generates reams of garbage. Having a single mutable 'visited' (local to isCyclic, and making hasCycle local to isCyclic too) seems more efficient, and cleaner if not pure fp...

Comment: This is a nice solution. I need to give this a try.

Comment: @Paul I like the immutable data structures because it simplifies the design and i can concentrate on the function i am working on. This might not be very performant as having a mutable visited nodes. But when compared to the readability, the performance hit will be negligible.

Comment: @Paul I agree with your comment that the hasCycle is not O(n^2). This can be made faster by changing the visited nodes as a HashSet instead of Seq. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Udayakumar Rayala, readability isn't very different in these two cases (I claim - see my answer). I would argue that the mutable one might even be more readable as it's more obvious (to me, anyway) what the 'visited' variable is for.

Comment: @Paul I think both versions are equally readable, just that the mutable version is more familiar to us than the immutable one. Regarding your comment about creating new Seqs generating garbage, I think you are not aware that all scala immutable collectins are Persistent data structures(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). Hence, the performance of both the code snippets are same and this code is functional as well.

Comment: @Udayakumar, that's exactly my point! From the page "persistent data structure is a data structure which always preserves the previous version of itself when it is modified;" - your version makes many copies of the visited collection, one for every recursive call. The previous version is no longer needed (so it's garbage). Mine has one mutable instance == less garbage. Whether the performance difference is noticeable in practice is an entirely different thing, of course...

Comment: @Paul Why do you worry about the garbage when the performance is not noticeable?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't noticeable, I said that was a different question. As a matter of good practice, however, I think one should be aware of how much garbage/memory one's code uses and - other things being equal - try not to use more than necessary

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by using '.find' instead of 'foreach' + 'return':

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Seq

```
def isCyclic() : Boolean = {
  def visit(node: MyNode): Boolean = {
      node.marker = 3

      val nodeId = node.id
      val children = vertexMap.getChildren(nodeId).toList.map(nodeId => id2nodeMap(nodeId))
      val found = children.exists(child => (3 == child.marker || (1 == child.marker && visit(child))))

      node.marker = 2

      found
  }

  lock.readLock().lock()
  try {
    nodes.foreach(node => node.marker = 1)
    nodes.exists(node => node.marker && visit(node))
  } finally {
    lock.readLock().unlock()
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, nice..... thx... it is a whole shift in programming.. very exciting stuff. Thx

Comment: you're welcome, consider giving a deep look at what Seq implement. Specially fold/groupBy/span - and don't hesitate to accept the answer if you problem is solved ;)

Comment: I need this as well:  found match {
        case None => false
        case Some(_) => true
      }

Comment: Oh sorry, simply use 'exists' instead of 'find', I've just edited my answer

Comment: And take a look at Udayakumar Rayala answer to avoid mutable state :)

Comment: mmm.. you should have a 'tick' next to answer, when clicking on it, he should move from gray to green

Answer (score 4):

**Summary:**
I have originated two solutions as generic FP functions which detect cycles within a directed graph. And per your implied preference, **the use of an early `return` to escape the recursive function has been eliminated**. The first, `isCyclic`, simply returns a Boolean as soon as the DFS (Depth First Search) repeats a node visit. The second, `filterToJustCycles`, returns a copy of the input `Map` filtered down to just the nodes involved in any/all cycles, and returns an empty `Map` when no cycles are found.

**Details:**
For the following, please Consider a directed graph encoded as such:

```
val directedGraphWithCyclesA: Map[String, Set[String]] =
  Map(
      "A" -> Set("B", "E", "J")
    , "B" -> Set("E", "F")
    , "C" -> Set("I", "G")
    , "D" -> Set("G", "L")
    , "E" -> Set("H")
    , "F" -> Set("G")
    , "G" -> Set("L")
    , "H" -> Set("J", "K")
    , "I" -> Set("K", "L")
    , "J" -> Set("B")
    , "K" -> Set("B")
  )
```

In both functions below, the type parameter `N` refers to whatever "Node" type you care to provide. It is important the provided "Node" type be both immutable and have stable `equals` and `hashCode` implementations (all of which occur automatically with use of immutable case classes).

---

The first function, `isCyclic`, is a similar in nature to the version of the solution provided by @the-archetypal-paul. It assumes the directed graph has been transformed into a `Map[N, Set[N]]` where `N` is the identity of a node in the graph.

If you need to see how to generically transform your custom directed graph implementation into a `Map[N, Set[N]]`, I have outlined a generic solution towards the end of this answer.

Calling the `isCyclic` function as such:

```
val isCyclicResult = isCyclic(directedGraphWithCyclesA)
```

will return:

```
`true`
```

No further information is provided. And the DFS (Depth First Search) is aborted at detection of the first repeated visit to a node.

```
def isCyclic[N](nsByN: Map[N, Set[N]]) : Boolean = {
  def hasCycle(nAndNs: (N, Set[N]), visited: Set[N] = Set[N]()): Boolean =
    if (visited.contains(nAndNs._1))
      true
    else
      nAndNs._2.exists(
        n =>
          nsByN.get(n) match {
            case Some(ns) =>
              hasCycle((n, ns), visited + nAndNs._1)
            case None =>
              false
          }
      )
  nsByN.exists(hasCycle(_))
}
```

---

The second function, `filterToJustCycles`, uses the set reduction technique to recursively filter away unreferenced root nodes in the Map. If there are no cycles in the supplied graph of nodes, then `.isEmpty` will be `true` on the returned `Map`. If however, there are any cycles, *all* of the nodes required to participate in any of the cycles are returned with all of the other non-cycle participating nodes filtered away.

Again, if you need to see how to generically transform your custom directed graph implementation into a `Map[N, Set[N]]`, I have outlined a generic solution towards the end of this answer.

Calling the `filterToJustCycles` function as such:

```
val cycles = filterToJustCycles(directedGraphWithCyclesA)
```

will return:

```
Map(E -> Set(H), J -> Set(B), B -> Set(E), H -> Set(J, K), K -> Set(B))
```

It's trivial to then create a traversal across this `Map` to produce any or all of the various cycle pathways through the remaining nodes.

```
def filterToJustCycles[N](nsByN: Map[N, Set[N]]): Map[N, Set[N]] = {
  def recursive(nsByNRemaining: Map[N, Set[N]], referencedRootNs: Set[N] = Set[N]()): Map[N, Set[N]] = {
    val (referencedRootNsNew, nsByNRemainingNew) = {
      val referencedRootNsNewTemp =
        nsByNRemaining.values.flatten.toSet.intersect(nsByNRemaining.keySet)
      (
          referencedRootNsNewTemp
        , nsByNRemaining.collect {
            case (t, ts) if referencedRootNsNewTemp.contains(t) && referencedRootNsNewTemp.intersect(ts.toSet).nonEmpty =>
              (t, referencedRootNsNewTemp.intersect(ts.toSet))
          }
        )
    }
    if (referencedRootNsNew == referencedRootNs)
      nsByNRemainingNew
    else
      recursive(nsByNRemainingNew, referencedRootNsNew)
  }
  recursive(nsByN)
}
```

---

**So, how does one generically transform a custom directed graph implementation into a `Map[N, Set[N]]`?**

In essence, "Go Scala case classes!"

First, let's define an example case of a real node in a pre-existing directed graph:

```
class CustomNode (
    val equipmentIdAndType: String //"A387.Structure" - identity is embedded in a string and must be parsed out
  , val childrenNodes: List[CustomNode] //even through Set is implied, for whatever reason this implementation used List
  , val otherImplementationNoise: Option[Any] = None
)
```

Again, this is just an example. Yours could involve subclassing, delegation, etc. The purpose is to have access to a something that will be able to fetch the two essential things to make this work:

- the identity of a node; i.e. something to distinguish it and makes it unique from all other nodes in the same directed graph
- a collection of the identities of the immediate children of a specific node - if the specific node doesn't have any children, this collection will be empty

Next, we define a helper object, `DirectedGraph`, which will contain the infrastructure for the conversion:

- `Node`: an adapter trait which will wrap `CustomNode`
- `toMap`: a function which will take a `List[CustomNode]` and convert it to a `Map[Node, Set[Node]]` (which is type equivalent to our target type of `Map[N, Set[N]]`)

Here's the code:

```
object DirectedGraph {
  trait Node[S, I] {
    def source: S
    def identity: I
    def children: Set[I]
  }

  def toMap[S, I, N <: Node[S, I]](ss: List[S], transformSToN: S => N): Map[N, Set[N]] = {
    val (ns, nByI) = {
      val iAndNs =
        ss.map(
          s => {
            val n =
              transformSToN(s)
            (n.identity, n)
          }
        )
      (iAndNs.map(_._2), iAndNs.toMap)
    }
    ns.map(n => (n, n.children.map(nByI(_)))).toMap
  }
}
```

Now, we must generate the actual adapter, `CustomNodeAdapter`, which will wrap each `CustomNode` instance. This adapter uses a case class in a very specific way; i.e. specifying two constructor parameters lists. It ensures the case class conforms to a `Set`'s requirement that a `Set` member have correct `equals` and `hashCode` implementations. For more details on why and how to use a case class this way, please see this [StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36162896/501113):

```
object CustomNodeAdapter extends (CustomNode => CustomNodeAdapter) {
  def apply(customNode: CustomNode): CustomNodeAdapter =
    new CustomNodeAdapter(fetchIdentity(customNode))(customNode) {}

  def fetchIdentity(customNode: CustomNode): String =
    fetchIdentity(customNode.equipmentIdAndType)

  def fetchIdentity(eiat: String): String =
    eiat.takeWhile(char => char.isLetter || char.isDigit)
}
abstract case class CustomNodeAdapter(identity: String)(customNode: CustomNode) extends DirectedGraph.Node[CustomNode, String] {
  val children =
    customNode.childrenNodes.map(CustomNodeAdapter.fetchIdentity).toSet
  val source =
    customNode
}
```

We now have the infrastructure in place. Let's define a "real world" directed graph consisting of `CustomNode`:

```
val customNodeDirectedGraphWithCyclesA =
  List(
      new CustomNode("A.x", List("B.a", "E.a", "J.a"))
    , new CustomNode("B.x", List("E.b", "F.b"))
    , new CustomNode("C.x", List("I.c", "G.c"))
    , new CustomNode("D.x", List("G.d", "L.d"))
    , new CustomNode("E.x", List("H.e"))
    , new CustomNode("F.x", List("G.f"))
    , new CustomNode("G.x", List("L.g"))
    , new CustomNode("H.x", List("J.h", "K.h"))
    , new CustomNode("I.x", List("K.i", "L.i"))
    , new CustomNode("J.x", List("B.j"))
    , new CustomNode("K.x", List("B.k"))
    , new CustomNode("L.x", Nil)
  )
```

Finally, we can now do the conversion which looks like this:

```
val transformCustomNodeDirectedGraphWithCyclesA =
  DirectedGraph.toMap[CustomNode, String, CustomNodeAdapter](customNodes1, customNode => CustomNodeAdapter(customNode))
```

And we can take `transformCustomNodeDirectedGraphWithCyclesA`, which is of type `Map[CustomNodeAdapter,Set[CustomNodeAdapter]]`, and submit it to the two original functions.

Calling the `isCyclic` function as such:

```
val isCyclicResult = isCyclic(transformCustomNodeDirectedGraphWithCyclesA)
```

will return:

```
`true`
```

Calling the `filterToJustCycles` function as such:

```
val cycles = filterToJustCycles(transformCustomNodeDirectedGraphWithCyclesA)
```

will return:

```
Map(
    CustomNodeAdapter(B) -> Set(CustomNodeAdapter(E))
  , CustomNodeAdapter(E) -> Set(CustomNodeAdapter(H))
  , CustomNodeAdapter(H) -> Set(CustomNodeAdapter(J), CustomNodeAdapter(K))
  , CustomNodeAdapter(J) -> Set(CustomNodeAdapter(B))
  , CustomNodeAdapter(K) -> Set(CustomNodeAdapter(B))
)
```

And if needed, this `Map` can then be converted back to `Map[CustomNode, List[CustomNode]]`:

```
cycles.map {
  case (customNodeAdapter, customNodeAdapterChildren) =>
    (customNodeAdapter.source, customNodeAdapterChildren.toList.map(_.source))
}
```

---

If you have any questions, issues or concerns, please let me know and I will address them ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Answer added just to show that the mutable-`visited` isn't too unreadable either (untested, though!)

```
def isCyclic() : Boolean =
{
     var visited = HashSet()

     def hasCycle(node:Node) = {
        if (visited.contains(node)) {
           true
        } else {
           visited :+= node
           children(node).exists(hasCycle(_))
        }
    }
    nodes.exists(hasCycle(_))
}

def children(node:Node) = vertexMap.getChildren(node.id).toList.map(nodeId => id2nodeMap(nodeId))
```

Comment: Would you agree that the first version with vals and no new would be the ideal FP implementation?

Comment: @JTS, I guess I would wonder why you wanted an "ideal" FP implementation. For me, readability, performance and robustness are important. FP can be a good way of achieving readability and robustnes (and some times performance) but for me its a means to an end, and not the end itself. I'm not normally concerned whether it's "ideal FP". And there is as much a `new` in that first version as there is in mine - both call `Hashset()` which returns a new `HashSet`

Answer (score 0):

If p = node => node.marker==1 && visit(node) and assuming nodes is a List you can pick any of the following:

- `nodes.filter(p).length>0`
- `nodes.count(p)>0`
- `nodes.exists(p)`  (I think the most relevant)

I am not sure of the relative complexity of each method and would appreciate a comment from fellow members of the community