# Scala: how to find and return a loopy path in a directed graph

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, graph, graph-algorithm

I wrote a function in Scala to find out and return a loopy path in a directed graph. The program is as followed, one of the arguments is a graph presented in an adjacent list, and the other is a start node. It returns a pair including a loopy path by a list of nodes.

I wonder there are more elegant ways to do so. Please share your thoughts if you would like to. Thanks.

```
  def GetACycle(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): (Boolean, List[String]) = {
    def explore(node: String, visits: List[String]): (Boolean, List[String]) = {
      if (visits.contains(node)) (true, (visits.+:(node)).reverse)
      else {
        if (maps(node).isEmpty) (false, List())
        else {
          val id = maps(node).indexWhere(x => explore(x, visits.+:(node))._1)
          if (id.!=(-1))
            explore(maps(node)(id), visits.+:(node))
          else
            (false, List())
        }
      }
    }
    explore(start, List())
  }
```

I felt I had to use the indexWhere in this situation, but I suppose it would have other ways to do that.

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for such kind of questions.

Comment: I just posted a more generic FP immutable answer on a related StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36144158/501113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array to check if you have already visited a node and not `visits.contains(node)`, it would give you the answer in constant time instead of linear time.

The overall complexity of your algorithm is exponential. For instance, if you run your algorithm on this graph:

```
0 -> 1, 2, ..., n
1 -> 2, ..., n
...
```

where there are `n` nodes and there are edges from `i` to `j` iff `i<j` then the node `i` will be explored `2^i` times.

Again you can solve this problem using an array (one array for all nodes) to ensure that each node is explored at most one time.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomash. Using array is a good suggestion. But this algorithm won't go exponential because it runs in depth first search and whenever it comes across a loopy path it will immediately return it and exit, it won't explore others. The .indexWhere(p=>Boolean) will stop once its predicate is true.

Comment: If you don't believe me when I say it is exponential, test your function on my example with n = 100.

Comment: I think the program travels a graph using depth first search(DFS), isn't it? DFS's complexity is O(n), reference to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search.

Comment: have you tested your code with my example ? DFS requires that you stop when you reach an already visited node and you don't do that.

Comment: I haven't run out the example. But in the program above, it does stop exploring and returns when it comes across a visited node, isn't it? As shown in the line, "if (visits.contains(node)) (true, (visits.+:(node)).reverse)".

Comment: It does stop exploring only when it comes across visited *on this branch*. If the node have been visited on another branch, you don't stop.

Comment: I think you are right about this. But I don't want to create a global variable to mark which node has been visited, which is not a functional programming way. Do you have any ideas about it? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want an array because "it's not functional", you can use a set that you pass to your recursive function.

Comment: Scala has an array data structure, and it's facile. I think I have to leave the visited set defined outside the explore recursive function, so that it would be globally available to all exploring processes. Thank you, Thomash.

Comment: Hi, Thomash, this is a good discussion. I did a test and printed recursively visited nodes in a hierarchical levels. The complexity (number of visited nodes) of the program above turns out to be c*2^n, c is a constant, and the n is the length of the first discovered loopy path. :)

Comment: By the way, I have another question post here, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19504/scala-how-to-break-this-curse-by-a-pure-functional-recursive-function, for an extensive discussion.