# Python list pop() much slower than list[1:]

Tags: python, performance, profiling

I recently wrote a quick and dirty BFS implementation, to find diamonds in a directed graph.
The BFS loop looked like this:

```
while toVisit:
    y = toVisit.pop()
    if y in visited: return "Found diamond"
    visited.add(y)
    toVisit.extend(G[y])
```

(`G` is the graph - a dictionary from node names to the lists of their neighbors)

Then comes the interesting part:
I thought that `list.pop()` is probably too slow, so I ran a profiler to compare the speed of this implementation with deque.pop - and got a bit of an improvement. Then I compared it with `y = toVisit[0]; toVisit = toVisit[1:]`, and to my surprise, the last implementation is actually the fastest one.

Does this make any sense?
Is there any performance reason to ever use `list.pop()` instead of the apparently much faster two-liner?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Could you share your micro-benchmark results in more detail?

Comment: Also, these are not equivalent. `pop()` takes from the back, your two liner takes from the front.

Comment: `toVisit.pop()` does not do the same thing as `y = toVisit[0]; toVisit = toVisit[1:]`: `pop()`'s default index is -1 (pop last), not 0 (pop first).

Comment: Good point. But the same repeats with list.pop(0). Might be worth noting that I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: @Eli: I profile with ipython's run -p. Is that output clear enough?

Comment: `pop(0)` is O(N) as all the items must be shifted. `pop()` however, is known to be a very fast operation as it removes an item from the end of the list, requiring no shifting.

Comment: Guy: I ran simple profiling and `pop` is *way* faster

Comment: On a side note, I don't think your loop detection algorithm works. For example, in a diamond shaped graph like A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D, your algorithm will wrongly detect a cycle. Use DFS instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525282/how-to-detect-if-a-directed-graph-is-cyclic

Comment: @spinlok - Thanks. I know that, but I was meaning to look for "non DAGs". I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: -1 because, given the answer, the question title is misleading.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev - I agree. But the traffic generated around it is interesting, so I'm not deleting it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have measured wrong. With cPython 2.7 on x64, I get the following results:

```
$ python -m timeit 'l = list(range(10000))' 'while l: l = l[1:]'
10 loops, best of 3: 365 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'l = list(range(10000))' 'while l: l.pop()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'import collections' \
         'l = collections.deque(list(range(10000)))' 'while l: l.pop()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 msec per loop
```

Comment: Same on my machine. I guess this means that my question is about ipython's profiling...

Comment: `l = list(range(10000))` takes a significant time to run. You can run `python -m timeit 'l = list(range(10000))'` and subtract that time from the combined time

Comment: @gnibbler The proper way is really to use `timeit`'s "setup" feature properly, like phihag did.

Comment: @Amber, you can't use the setup feature (`-s`) here as the list would be empty after the first run.

Comment: Just a small point but that answer is technically measuring different things. ```pop``` without parameters defaults to **last** element. But the task it to remove **first** element. The answer is still ```pop``` is faster, but the numbers are different. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: and deque should be popleft() not pop()

Comment: Technically true but if you're only doing `pop(0)` you could reverse the list and achieve the same results in `pop()` time.  Since you're destroying the list it shouldn't matter if you modify it beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Use generators for perfomance

`python -m timeit 'import itertools' 'l=iter(xrange(10000))' 'while next(l, None): l,a = itertools.tee(l)'`

`1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.986 usec per loop`

Comment: How is that an answer? And posting the benchmark results without comparison doesn't mean much.

Comment: That's an addition for phihag's answer. in all(his and mine) examples l is the rest of the list on each iteration. time is mesuared equivalently. his code creates kind of copy of a list on each iteration, mine doesn't.