# Algorithm to determine if a graph is a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

What is a simple algorithm to determine if a graph, given as an adjacency matrix, is a tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tree is a graph without cycles, so to detect if your graph is a tree, check to see if it has any cycles.  This can be done by traversing the matrix, retaining a history of every visited node and upon visiting a node, checking to see if it was in the set of nodes visited.

Here's a previous SO post about detecting cycles.  It's a starting point:
[How to detect if a directed graph is cyclic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525282/how-to-detect-if-a-directed-graph-is-cyclic)

You can also study up on graph traversals and adjacency matrices, to give you a better grounding in what you need to do.

If after all of this, you still need help, you can post what you have so far.

Comment: If the graph is undirected, this will not work.

Using BFS and counting distance,  while traversing we can eliminate nodes which are 1 distance away and add the rest to the queue.  Now checking to see if the node was visited will suffice.

Answer (score 7):

You can count amount of edges (E) and amount of verticies (V) if E + 1 = V you can assume that it's a tree. You also need to check that there is one connected component. To figure out that it only contains one component you may use either DFS or BFS.

Comment: Sure, but in order for DFS or BFS to terminate on a graph that may contain cycles, you will need to record somewhere whether each vertex has already been visited -- and if you see a previously-visited vertex, you already know the graph has a cycle, without having to count edges! :-P

Comment: Just checking that graph doesn't have cycles is not sufficient. Suppose you have isolated verticies or several connected components.

Comment: Absolutely agree with the >>will need to record somewhere whether each vertex has already been visited. If you have knowlege of E and V in advance you may first just check E + 1 == V if not even do not do traversing.

Comment: When did I say that DFS/BFS should only be run on one component?  As with your solution, it needs to be run on each component.

Comment: :-) ok, I'm fine with do dfs(anyvertex); and then if no cycles and all visited => tree, otherwise not.

Comment: In DFS you can check for back-edges.  Use a counter and increase for pre-vertex visit on entering and increase on post-vertex visit on exiting.  On completion of DFS, if an edge (u,v) exists where pre(u) > pre(v) and post(u) < post(v) you have a backedge, and therefore a cycle.  O(|V| + |E|).

Answer (score 2):

Some code (in Python):

```
def is_tree(G):
    n = len(G)
    M = [False]*n

    def dfs_tree(u, v):
        M[v] = True

        return all(w==u or not M[w] and dfs_tree(v, w) for w in range(n) if G[v][w])

    return dfs_tree(0, 0) and all(M)

print is_tree([
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
])

'''
 0-1 
 |
 2

 True
'''


print is_tree([
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
])

'''
 0-1 
 |/
 2 

 False
'''
```