# How can I access to adjacency lists inside the Vertex object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, digraphs

I built a graph in Python, based on Vertex and graph classes, but in `isCycleUtil()` method, when I try to access Vertex object by doing `for i in self.vert_dict[v]`, I get a TypeError: Vertex object not iterable.

Can you help me to fix It and have a functional isCycleUtil method?

```
class Vertex:
def __init__(self, node):
    self.id = node
    self.adjacent = {}

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + ' adjacent: ' + str([x.id for x in self.adjacent])

def add_neighbor(self, neighbor, weight=0):
    self.adjacent[neighbor] = weight

def get_connections(self):
    return self.adjacent.keys()

def get_id(self):
    return self.id

def get_weight(self, neighbor):
    return self.adjacent[neighbor]

def set_weight(self, neighbor, newvalue):
    self.adjacent[neighbor] = newvalue
```

and the graph class:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self):
    self.vert_dict = {}
    self.num_vertices = 0

def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.vert_dict.values())

def add_vertex(self, node):
    self.num_vertices += 1
    new_vertex = Vertex(node)
    self.vert_dict[node] = new_vertex
    return new_vertex

def get_vertex(self, n):
    if n in self.vert_dict:
        return self.vert_dict[n]
    else:
        return None

def add_edge(self, frm, to, cost = 0):
    if frm not in self.vert_dict:
        self.add_vertex(frm)
    if to not in self.vert_dict:
        self.add_vertex(to)

    self.vert_dict[frm].add_neighbor(self.vert_dict[to], cost)

def get_vertices(self):
    return self.vert_dict.keys()

def isCyclicUtil(self,v,visited,parent):

    #Mark the current node as visited
    if not visited[v]:
        visited[v]= True
        parent[v] = True
        #Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        for i in self.vert_dict[v]:
            # If the node is not visited then recurse on it
            if  (not visited[i] and self.isCyclicUtil(i,visited,parent)):
                return True
            elif  (not parent[i]):
                return True
    parent[v] = False
    return False


#Returns true if the graph contains a cycle, else false.
def isCyclic(self):
    # Mark all the vertices as not visited
    visited = {}
    parent = {}
    for i in self.vert_dict:
        visited[i] = False
        parent[i] = False
    # Call the recursive helper function to detect cycle in different
    #DFS trees
    for i in self.vert_dict:
        if(self.isCyclicUtil(i,visited,parent)):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error you need to replace:

```
 for i in self.vert_dict[v]
```

with

```
 for i in self.vert_dict[v].get_connections()
```

and use:

```
visited[v.get_id()]
```

instead of

```
visited[v]
```

to avoid KeyError

Your graph is directed so correct algoritm is descibed in this topic:

[How to detect if a directed graph is cyclic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525282/how-to-detect-if-a-directed-graph-is-cyclic)

You need to change implementation of isCyclicuntil method:

```
def isCyclicUtil(self, v, visited, parent):

    # Mark the current node as visited
    if not visited[v]:
        visited[v] = True
        # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        for i in self.vert_dict[v].get_connections():
            # If the node is not visited then recurse on it
            if visited[i.get_id()]:
                return True
            elif self.isCyclicUtil(i.get_id(), visited, parent):
                return True
    return False
```