# Confusions on finding a cycle in a possibly unconnected directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, directed-graph

I am confused about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584478/1383356). Why can't DFS decide if there is a cycle in a directed graph while visiting each node and each edge at most once? Using the [white, gray, black](http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dbabcock/PastCourses/cs360/lectures/lecture17.html) method, one should be able to find a cycle if there is a backward edge.

For an unconnected directed graph, why can't one do the following: run DFS from an arbitrary node `v` and visit as many nodes as `v` is connected to, then run DFS on another unvisited arbitrary node in the graph, if any, until all nodes are visited?

It seems to me that DFS should be able to find a cycle if it exists in at most `o(|V|+|E|)` time. Is this claim in the [above mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584478/1383356) wrong?

> "It is possible to visit a node multiple times in a DFS without a
>   cycle existing"

Moreover, as this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526371/1383356) suggest, if a cycle exists, DFS should find it after exploring a maximum of `|V|` edges, so the run time is really `O(|V|)`.

What am I missing?

**Update and conclusions:**

Based on Pham Trung's comments, it looks like the "simple DFS" in that answer refers to a DFS starting from one node in a strongly connected graph. As I understand it, for a general case that the graph might be unconnected, the following statements should be true:

- Using DFS and starting from an arbitrary unvisited node in an unconnected graph, it is true that each node might be visited more than once, but using white-gray-black coloring, a cycle -if exists - will be correctly found.
- The run time of such a DFS algorithm is `O(d.|V|+|E|)`, where `d` is the max in-degree among all nodes (i.e. the max time that we can visit each node using such  DFS-based algorithm)
- Moreover, as this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526371/1383356) suggest, if after exploring `O(|V|)` edges, a cycle was not found, it does not exist. So the runtime is really `O(|V|)`.

Comment: Try these: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph

Comment: visiting each what?

Comment: @kilotaras: Fixed the typos.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine we have this simple graph with these edges:

- 1 -> 3
- 2 -> 3

  ```
  1 ----->3
          ^
          |
  2--------
  ```

So, in our first dfs, we discover node 1 and 3. And, we continue to do dfs with node 2, now, we encounter node 3 again, but is this a cycle? obviously not.

One more example:

- 1 -> 3
- 1 -> 2
- 2 -> 3

  ```
  1----->3
  |      ^
  |      |
  |      |
  v      |
  2-------
  ```

So, starting with node 1, we visit node 3, back to node 2, and now, we encounter node 3 one more time, and, this case, it is not a cycle also.

As far as I understand  the **simple depth-first-search** from Jay Conrod's answer means, a normal, original DFS (only checking for connected component). In the same answer, he also described how to modify **simple DFS** to find the existence of cycle, which is exactly the algorithm OP has cited. And right below, another answer also mentioned a lemma in the famous `Introduction to algorithm` book

> A directed graph G is acyclic if and only if a depth-first search of G yields no back edges

In short, OP's understanding to detect cycle in directed graph is correct, it is just some complexities and shortcuts have lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: DFS algorithm with white, gray, and black colors for nodes only declares an edge to be a backedge when the color is gray (i.e. that node's descendants is being visited) Once all decendants are visited it will be turned into black color. In your first example, after visiting node 3, its color will be set to black, and when you get to 3 from 2 again because it is not gray, no cycle will be declared. Same thing for your second example. So  the algorithm works correctly.

Comment: @Ari Actually, as far as I understand `a simple depth-first-search is not good enough to find a cycle` from Jay Conrod's answer which means, a normal DFS (only checking for connected component). But, in the same answer, he also described how to modify `simple DFS` to find the existence of cycle, which is exactly the algorithm you have cited. And right below, another answer also mentioned a lemma in the famous Introduction to algorithm book `A directed graph G is acyclic if and only if a depth-first search of G yields no back edges`

Comment: @Ari I think it is because he didn't clearly define what can be considered `simple DFS` that causing your confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. I updated my question. I appreciate if you can confirm my conclusions.